# Looping custom post object with Advance Custom Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying the following, as from http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/post-object/, but it only outputs empty divs:

```
<?php $post_objects = get_field('project_experts');

if( $post_objects ): ?>
    <div class="row expert">
    <?php foreach( $post_objects as $post): ?>
    <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <div class="mt-one-half">
            <h3><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

However I know the info is there as when I try `<?php print_r( get_field('project_experts')  ); ?>` I get:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [project_expert] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] => 763 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2014-03-27 17:57:29 [post_date_gmt] => 2014-03-27 17:57:29 [post_content] =>
```

etc etc.

Any pointers for grabbing values from the array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. You just need to go one level deeper into the array that `get_field` is returning.

```
<?php foreach( $post_objects as $array): ?>
    <?php foreach( $array as $obj): ?>

<?php setup_postdata($obj); ?>
    <div class="mt-one-half">
        <h3><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a></h3>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
//etc... as before
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I thought an expert would see it off the bat. :)

Comment: No problem. I clicked through to see your website btw. Gorgeous design work. Best of luck and wisdom to you.

Comment: Thanks again larsAnders!